# In terminator is it possible to indicate if the current terminal had been maximized (Ctrl+Shift+X) in a split window?

Tags: terminator

When I have multiple terminator windows open, some of which have been split into multiple terminals, I sometimes lose track of the inactive split terminals after maximizing one of the terminals in the split window. I would like to avoid having to hit `<Ctrl> + <Shift> + X` in every terminator window to see if there are hidden terminals.

Is is possible to indicate in the maximized active terminal title or in the window title that there are hidden split terminals?

For example in a terminator window:

```
<Ctrl> + <Shift> + E    # split window into a terminal-left and terminal-right
<Ctrl> + <Shift> + X    # maximize the terminal-right in the window, terminal left is now hidden
```

Can the terminator window or the maximized active terminal-right indicate that there is a hidden terminal?